# Matlab Vectorization - none-zero matrix row indices to cell

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am working with Matlab.

I have a binary square matrix. For each row, there is one or more entries of 1. I want to go through each row of this matrix and return the index of those 1s and store them in the entry of a cell.

I was wondering if there is a way to do this without looping over all the rows of this matrix, as for loop is really slow in Matlab.

For example, my matrix

```
M = 0 1 0
    1 0 1
    1 1 1
```

Then eventually, I want something like

```
A = [2]
    [1,3]
    [1,2,3]
```

So `A` is a cell.

Is there a way to achieve this goal without using for loop, with the aim of calculating the result more quickly?

Comment: Do you want the result to be fast or do you want the result to avoid `for` loops? For this problem, with modern versions of MATLAB, I strongly suspect a `for` loop to be the fastest solution. If you have a performance problem I suspect you're looking in the wrong place for the solution based on outdated advice.

Comment: @Will I want the results to be fast. My matrix is very big. The run time is about 30s in my computer by using for loop. I want to know if there are some clever vectorization operations or, mapReduce, etc that can increase the speed.

Comment: I suspect, you can't. Vectorization works on accurately described vectors and matrices, but your result allows for vectors of different lengths. Thus, my assumption is, that you'll always have some explicit loop or some loop-in-disguise like `cellfun`.

Comment: @ftxx how big? And how many `1`s in a typical row? I wouldn't expect a `find` loop to take anything close to 30s for anything small enough to fit on physical memory.

Comment: @ftxx Please see my updated answer, I've edited since it was accepted with a minor performance improvement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the bottom of this answer is some benchmarking code, since you clarified that you're interested in performance rather than arbitrarily avoiding `for` loops.

In fact, I think `for` loops are probably the most performant option here. Since the "new" (2015b) JIT engine was introduced ([source](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/02/12/run-code-faster-with-the-new-matlab-execution-engine/)) `for` loops are not inherently slow - in fact they are optimised internally.

You can see from the benchmark that the `mat2cell` option offered by ThomasIsCoding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60148893/3978545) is very slow...

[image: Comparison 1]

If we get rid of that line to make the scale clearer, then my `splitapply` method is fairly slow, obchardon's [accumarray option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60149134/3978545) is a bit better, but the fastest (and comparable) options are either using `arrayfun` (as also suggested by Thomas) or a `for` loop. Note that `arrayfun` is basically a `for` loop in disguise for most use-cases, so this isn't a surprising tie!

[image: Comparison 2]

<strike>**I would recommend you use a `for` loop for increased code readability and the best performance.**</strike>

**Edit**:

If we assume that looping is the fastest approach, we can make some optimisations around the `find` command.

Specifically

- Make `M` logical. As the below plot shows, this can be faster for relatively small `M`, but slower with the trade-off of type conversion for large `M`.
- Use a logical `M` to index an array `1:size(M,2)` instead of using `find`. This avoids the slowest part of the loop (the `find` command) and outweighs the type conversion overhead, making it the quickest option.

**Here is my recommendation for best performance:**

```
function A = f_forlooplogicalindexing( M )
    M = logical(M);
    k = 1:size(M,2);
    N = size(M,1);
    A = cell(N,1);
    for r = 1:N
        A{r} = k(M(r,:));
    end
end
```

I've added this to the benchmark below, here is the comparison of loop-style approaches:

[image: Comparison 3]

Benchmarking code:

```
rng(904); % Gives OP example for randi([0,1],3)
p = 2:12; 
T = NaN( numel(p), 7 );
for ii = p
    N = 2^ii;
    M = randi([0,1],N);

    fprintf( 'N = 2^%.0f = %.0f\n', log2(N), N );

    f1 = @()f_arrayfun( M );
    f2 = @()f_mat2cell( M );
    f3 = @()f_accumarray( M );
    f4 = @()f_splitapply( M );
    f5 = @()f_forloop( M );
    f6 = @()f_forlooplogical( M );
    f7 = @()f_forlooplogicalindexing( M );

    T(ii, 1) = timeit( f1 ); 
    T(ii, 2) = timeit( f2 ); 
    T(ii, 3) = timeit( f3 ); 
    T(ii, 4) = timeit( f4 );  
    T(ii, 5) = timeit( f5 );
    T(ii, 6) = timeit( f6 );
    T(ii, 7) = timeit( f7 );
end

plot( (2.^p).', T(2:end,:) );
legend( {'arrayfun','mat2cell','accumarray','splitapply','for loop',...
         'for loop logical', 'for loop logical + indexing'} );
grid on;
xlabel( 'N, where M = random N*N matrix of 1 or 0' );
ylabel( 'Execution time (s)' );

disp( 'Done' );

function A = f_arrayfun( M )
    A = arrayfun(@(r) find(M(r,:)),1:size(M,1),'UniformOutput',false);
end
function A = f_mat2cell( M )
    [i,j] = find(M.');
    A = mat2cell(i,arrayfun(@(r) sum(j==r),min(j):max(j)));
end
function A = f_accumarray( M )
    [val,ind] = ind2sub(size(M),find(M.'));
    A = accumarray(ind,val,[],@(x) {x});
end
function A = f_splitapply( M )
    [r,c] = find(M);
    A = splitapply( @(x) {x}, c, r );
end
function A = f_forloop( M )
    N = size(M,1);
    A = cell(N,1);
    for r = 1:N
        A{r} = find(M(r,:));
    end
end
function A = f_forlooplogical( M )
    M = logical(M);
    N = size(M,1);
    A = cell(N,1);
    for r = 1:N
        A{r} = find(M(r,:));
    end
end
function A = f_forlooplogicalindexing( M )
    M = logical(M);
    k = 1:size(M,2);
    N = size(M,1);
    A = cell(N,1);
    for r = 1:N
        A{r} = k(M(r,:));
    end
end
```

Comment: Already saw and upvoted. :-) Still waiting for Luis; he sure has some black MATLAB magic for that.

Comment: @Hans Haha yeah although his usual bag of tricks (implicit expansion, clever indexing, ...) usually keeps things as matrices, the bottleneck here is summarising in cells

Comment: Note that these times are strongly dependent on the sparsity of `M`. If, for instance, only 5% of elements are populated `M = randi([0,20],N) == 20;` then the `for` loop is by far the slowest and your `arrayfun` method wins.

Comment: @HansHirse :-) My approach would have been `accumarray` without `ind2sub`, but it is slower than the `for` loop

Answer (score 2):

You can try `arrayfun` like below, which sweep through rows of `M`

```
A = arrayfun(@(r) find(M(r,:)),1:size(M,1),'UniformOutput',false)

A =
{
  [1,1] =  2
  [1,2] =

     1   3

  [1,3] =

     1   2   3

}
```

or (a slower approach by `mat2cell`)

```
[i,j] = find(M.');
A = mat2cell(i,arrayfun(@(r) sum(j==r),min(j):max(j)))

A =
{
  [1,1] =  2
  [2,1] =

     1
     3

  [3,1] =

     1
     2
     3

}
```

Comment: Although `arrayfun` is basically a loop-in-disguise, so this may fail on both fronts of 1) avoiding loops and 2) being fast, as hoped for by the OP

Answer (score 2):

Using [accumarray](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html#bt4vy9n-5):

```
M = [0 1 0
     1 0 1
     1 1 1];

[val,ind] = find(M.');

A = accumarray(ind,val,[],@(x) {x});
```

Comment: Execution time in Octave and MATLAB Online is about 2x of a simple for loop like: `MM{I} = find(M(I, :))`.

Comment: @Hans you might want to see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60149557/3978545)

Comment: yeah, since the size of each cell are not the same, this problem can not be fully vectorized (or there is a trick that I have not see). It's only a solution that hide the for loop.

Comment: No need for `ind2sub`: `[ii, jj] = find(M); accumarray(ii, jj, [], @(x){x})`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [strfind](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) :

```
A = strfind(cellstr(char(M)), char(1));
```

Comment: I (lazily) haven't even looked in the docs, but would this be quicker using actual `string` types, rather than chars? There are lots of optimisations for strings, hence why they exist...

Comment: @Wolfie I think numeric arrays are more similar to  char arrays than strings so  conversion of numeric array to character array should be more straightforward than conversion to string  .

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I added a benchmark, the results show that **a for loop is more efficient than `accumarray`**.

---

You can use`find` and `accumarray`:

```matlab
[c, r] = find(A');
C = accumarray(r, c, [], @(v) {v'});
```

The matrix is transposed (`A'`) because `find` groups by column.

**Example:**

```
A = [1 0 0 1 0
     0 1 0 0 0
     0 0 1 1 0
     1 0 1 0 1];

%  Find nonzero rows and colums
[c, r] = find(A');

%  Group row indices for each columns
C = accumarray(r, c, [], @(v) {v'});

% Display cell array contents
celldisp(C)
```

Output:

```
C{1} = 
     1     4

C{2} = 
     2

C{3} =
     3     4

C{4} = 
     1     3     5
```

**Benchmark:**

```matlab
m = 10000;
n = 10000;

A = randi([0 1], m,n);

disp('accumarray:')
tic
[c, r] = find(A');
C = accumarray(r, c, [], @(v) {v'});
toc
disp(' ')

disp('For loop:')
tic
C = cell([size(A,1) 1]);
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    C{i} = find(A(i,:));
end
toc
```

Result:

```
accumarray:
Elapsed time is 2.407773 seconds.

For loop:
Elapsed time is 1.671387 seconds.
```

A for loop is more efficient than `accumarray`...

Comment: This is pretty much the method already [proposed by obchardon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60149134/3978545), no?

Comment: Yes, I was a little slow, I saw his answer after I posted mine.